# Parse The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: xamarin.ios, parse-platform, xamarin

I am trying to retrieve a parse object but I am having some problems with it this is the class i am using to define the business object. It throws the following error The given key was not present in the dictionary. I just not sure what the problem is with the class ?

```cs
public class Clinics
{

    public string ObjectId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    public string Data1 { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string locationGeo  { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdAt  { get; set; }
    public string Town  { get; set; }
    public DateTime updatedAt  { get; set; }
    public string Data2 { get; set; }
    public string Data3 { get; set; }
    public string Lat { get; set; }

    public string Lng { get; set; }

}
```

This is how  I am getting back my data set form parse.com

```cs
public static async Task<List<Clinics>> GetAll ()
{
    var query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("clinics").OrderBy ("Name");
    var ie = await query.FindAsync ();
    var tl = new List<Clinics> ();

    foreach (var t in ie) {
        tl.Add (FromParseObject (t));
    }
    return tl;
 }
```

FromParseObect

```cs
static Clinics FromParseObject (ParseObject po)
{
    var t = new Clinics();
    t.Lat = Convert.ToString(po["Lat"]);
    //t.Lng= Convert.ToString(po["Long"]);
    t.Name =   Convert.ToString(po["Name"]);
    t.Address1 = "";
    t.Data1 = "";
    t.Data2 = "";
    t.Data3 = "";
    t.locationGeo = "";
    t.Town = "";
    t.PostCode = "";

    return t;
}
```

Am I missing some kind of standard parse definations that I should have in my class as I am getting the following error

The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Comment: Which specific line throws the exception?

Comment: Jason did u again down grade me it seems every question i post u down grade at the min I am not asking the impossible so please stop

Comment: I would like to report this downgrade as being in accurate

Comment: I didn't down vote you.  Somebody else down voted you.  I asked you for more information, so that I might actually be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jason mentioned, you should specify which line is causing the error.

I'll go off of the assumption that you are referring to commented out line being the erroneous one.

The index you are trying to access:

```cs
t.Lng= Convert.ToString(po["Long"]);
```

is not the same as the property:

```cs
public string Lng { get; set; }
```

"Long" vs "Lng".